# speed limits for roads

Tags: geospatial, usa, transportation, map

Shapefiles of roads can be downloaded from the US Census's [TIGER database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologically_Integrated_Geographic_Encoding_and_Referencing) and from local municipalities but what about speed limit data?

Like from point A to point B on a given roadway the speed limit is x mph, while from point B to point C, the speed limit on that same roadway might be y mph.

Is this data available anywhere as a shapefile or anything?

If it's not available on a national level might it be available at various state or local levels?

[Data Source for Speed Limits](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/675/1306) is a similar question but it's from 10 years ago and the answer looks less like a definitive answer and more like a "you can make certain educated guesses based on this ruleset" type of answer.